# Jess walked for 45 minutes at 3km/h and then ran for 30 minutes at x km/h. At the end of the time she was 6 km from the starting point. Find x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't how to create  a second equation without triggering circular reasoning.

Comment: What is your first equation, then? (Because there is only one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully you know that $$\text{speed}=\frac{\text{distance}}{\text{time}}$$

So, when she was walking we can say that \begin{align}3\text{km/h}&=\frac{d_w}{45\text{ minutes}}\\
3\text{km/h}&=\frac{d_w}{0.75\text{ hours}}\\
d_w&=3\text{km/h}\times 0.75\text{ hours}\\
&=2.25\text{km}\end{align}

When she was running, we can say that

\begin{align}x&=\frac{d_r\text{km}}{30\text{ minutes}}\\
&=\frac{(6-d_w)\text{km}}{0.5\text{ hours}}\\
&=\frac{3.75\text{km}}{0.5\text{ hours}}\\
&=7.5\text{km/h}\end{align}

I have left all the units in the equations, so you can hopefully see why we need to convert the hours to minutes

Comment: Hi i just checked and the answer is correct, but i still don't understand on how you came with the answer dr = 6-dw.

Comment: You know that she travelled a total distance of $6$km. If $2.25$ of those were when she was walking then the remaining $3.75$ must have been covered while running

Comment: Hmm, but isn't she still like 6 km from the starting point, indicating that the total distance is more than 6 km?

Comment: No, the start point is where she started walking. So she walked for 45 minutes, covering a distance of $2.25$km and then ran for 30 minutes. When she stopped running, she was $6$km away from where she originally started walking, meaning she has run a distance of $6-2.25=3.75$km

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Note that $45\,\mathrm{min} = 0.75\,\mathrm h$ and $30\,\mathrm{min} = 0.5\,\mathrm h$.

Recall that $\mathrm{speed} = \dfrac{\mathrm{distance}}{\mathrm{time}}\implies \mathrm{distance} = \mathrm{speed}\cdot\mathrm{time}$.

Let $d_1$ be the distance Jess walked and let $d_2$ be the distance Jess ran. The total distance covered by Jess is $d_1 + d_2$. Can you proceed from here?